# i was trying to make an app using python and kivy although code is fine and not throwing any error i am getting black screen

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
Window.size = (500,700)
Builder.load_file('calc.kv')
class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass
class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
     App().run()
```

this is my calc.py please help me to solve the problem

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
```

BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

```
TextInput:
    id: clac_input
    text: "0"
    halign: "right"
    font_size : 65
    size_hint: (1, .15)

GridLayout:
    cols:4
    rows:5

Button:
    size_hint: (.2, .2)
    font_size: 32
    text: "%"
```

this is my calc.kv

Comment: please let me know if any assistance is reqired

Comment: thank you very much it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing the app is not returning any screens for your widgets to show on. I've changed a bit of your code to what I believe is correct that solves the issue.

**.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Window.size = (500,700)
Builder.load_file('calc.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     App().run()
```

**calc.kv**

```
<WindowManager>:
    Screen1

<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:4
            rows:5

            TextInput:
                id: clac_input
                text: "0"
                halign: "right"
                font_size : 65
                size_hint: (1, .15)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "%"
```